# How can one tell if a feature request posted here has been seen by someone who can attend to it?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

When one posts a feature request here, is there any way to tell whether any responsible person has read it, i.e. a person responsible for developing new features?

Comment: Have you tried a ouija board?

Comment: @AsafKaragila ; ha ha ha ha.  Are you saying there is no way to contact people responsible for this sort of thing? Are they all hiding in a cave in Afghanistan?  Do they exist at all? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Just wait 6-8 weeks.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I often wondered about this as well. Which is why I upvoted your question, and promptly remembered Antonius Block talking to Death in his priest disguise, in the confessional booth. "*Block: I cry to Him in the dark, but there seems to be no one there.*"

Comment: @quid : What is supposed to happen after six-to-eight weeks? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, I thought [this SE meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/) was more well known. (I am in the process of writing an actual answer too.)

Comment: @quid : I never heard of that before.

Answer (score 10):

The standard procedure to complete a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is to add a mod-only status-tag  [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). This happens, as can be seen from inspecting the relevant tags, also on per-site metas from time to time.  Other than that it can happen that CMs or other SE-staff comment on or answer such requests, implying that they saw the request.

There is, however, no separate "seen" feature, that indicates that somebody from SE has had a look; this might also not be very  meaningful as information.

As long as there is no status tag applied the request can be considered as "alive" or "under consideration."

Requests on [meta.se] seem to get more attention than requests on per-site metas, and there one also has the possibility to place a bounty for extra visibility.